# How to split responsibilities while keeping its use consistent?

Tags: c++

I have a number of classes forming a class hierarchy with base classes and their inheritances. Each class is quite large by taking several responsibilities, although those responsibilities are not coupled. I put the different responsibilities together in a class because I can easily use them consistently(I cannot express it very clearly, please see the illustrating code). But this seems not a good design. How can I split the large class while keeping it easy to use? Thanks for your suggestion and comments! The below please find the illustrating code.

```
// Base class.
class Base
{
public:
    // For responsibility A
    virtual void A1();
    virtual void A2();
    ...

    // For responsibility B
    virtual void B1();
    virtual void B2();
    ...

    // More responsibilites.
    ...
};

// Derived class 1.
class Derived_1 : public Base
{...};

// More derived classes.
...

// A function use it.
void Fun()
{
    Base* p = new Derived_1;
    p->A1(); // Here A1 and B1 are binded in the class Base, thus it make sure
    p->B1(); // their uses are consistent. If they are separated, how to ensure it? 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By having more than one responsibility in a class, you're breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of design.

Generally, good designs follow the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

Break up your classes.

1. Define an interface for each responsibility.
2. Try not to use multiple inheritance  - [use composition instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

I've added some sample code to illustrate the concept:

```
#include <iostream>

//Interface for A
class ResponsibilityA
{
    public:
    virtual ~ResponsibilityA(){};
        virtual void A1() = 0;
        virtual void A2() = 0;
};


//Interface for B
class ResponsibilityB
{
        public:
    virtual ~ResponsibilityB(){};
        virtual void B1() = 0;
        virtual void B2() = 0;
};

//Concrete classes for each interface
class ResponsibilityAExecutor : public ResponsibilityA
{
        public:
        virtual void A1(){ std::cout<<"A1 executed\n"; };
        virtual void A2(){ std::cout<<"A2 executed\n"; };
};

class ResponsibilityBExecutor : public ResponsibilityB
{
        public:
        virtual void B1(){ std::cout<<"B1 executed\n"; }
        virtual void B2(){ std::cout<<"B2 executed\n"; }
};

// Now we use the interface implementations in a class that needs
// to combine both responsibilities
class PlanExecutor
{
public:
        PlanExecutor( ResponsibilityA& a, ResponsibilityB& b ) : 
        a_(a),
        b_(b)
        {

        }
        void ExecutePlan()
        {
                std::cout<<"Executing first part of the plan:\n";
                a_.A1();
                b_.B1();
                std::cout<<"Executing second part of the plan\n";
                a_.A2();
                b_.B2();
        }
private:
        ResponsibilityA &a_;
        ResponsibilityB &b_;    
};

int main()
{
        ResponsibilityAExecutor a;
        ResponsibilityBExecutor b;
        PlanExecutor p(a,b);
        p.ExecutePlan();
        return 0;
}
```

Finally, I also need to emphasize the importance of naming.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if Responsibilities of A and B are totally different the create separate classes for both of them and let the child implement what they want this way some child want only A or only B or both and it keeps it manageable and maintainable

```
// Base class.
class Base
{
public:
    // For responsibility A
**Goes to class A**
    virtual void A1();
    virtual void A2();
    ...


**//Goes to class B**
    // For responsibility B
    virtual void B1();
    virtual void B2();
    ...

    // More responsibilites.
    ...
};

// Derived class 1.
class Derived_1 : public Base **//inherits from A**
{...}; 

class Derived_2:Public A,Public B
```